# CoordinatorLayout inside BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottomsheetdialog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDJP6.gif)

BottomSheetDialog layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <Toolbar>
  <RecyclerView>
```

How to change the behavior in the demo screen record to scrolling at the RecyclerView areas, BottomSheetDialog peek height up first until at top, and then RecyclerView list begin scrolling after